# Not able to stop recursive jQuery function execution

Tags: jquery

```
function plotmarker(z=false) {
    console.log(z);
    if(z >= assets.length || z==-1) {
        return false;
    }
    if(z!=-1) {
        //console.log(z +'  ===  '+ assets.length);
        var myLatLng = {lat: parseFloat(assets[z].lati), lng: parseFloat(assets[z].longi)}; 
        jQuery('#impforpause').attr('data-z', z);
        jQuery('#impforpause').attr('data-latlng', myLatLng);

        var result = [parseFloat(assets[z].lati), parseFloat(assets[z].longi)];
        transition(result);
        z++;
        steps++;
        if(steps == 8) {
            console.log(result);
            map.panTo(myLatLng);
            //map.setZoom(13);
            steps = 0;

            var thisasset = assets[z];
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: myLatLng,
                map: map,
                draggable: false,
                icon : "<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/newicon/circle_orange.png",
            });

            (function (marker, thisasset){
                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function (e){
                    infoWindow.setContent(popup(thisasset));
                    infoWindow.open(map, marker);
                });
            })(marker, thisasset); 
        }

        setTimeout(function(){ plotmarker(z) }, 500);
    }
}
```

This is my jQuery function I am calling the function from inside the execution  itself once its been initiated by a click. What I am not able to do is, I want to stop the execution of this function by another click. I tried passing `z==-1` as a parameter but no success.

Does anybody know how to achieve this?

Comment: You're trying to use a default parameter `function ...(z=false)`, this isn't supported by many browsers yet (you don't seem to use other es6 features). You should keep a flag variable outside of your function. Check that flag and stop execution when it's false.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/gLba4bet/

Comment: Hi Sniels, Can you help me out here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If i understand correctly, you cannot call it again and pass z = -1, because then you will actually run it again.
What you need to do is have a flag outside the function that will say that its not active anymore.
Something like:

```
var isActive = true;

function plotmarker(z=false){
  if (!isActive) return;
....
}
```

And in your onClick (the second one) set it to false .

Comment: Hi Kinnza, Still not able to work it out. Here is the simplified fiddle

Comment: @SandeepPujare, here's how to do it, https://jsfiddle.net/gLba4bet/1/. I used a boolean to stop the recursion. I also made sure the buttons aren't clickable when your recursions are running to prevent double executions.

Comment: Both examples are awesome. Thanks guys